Mathematica crashes when trying to use NIntegrate on a complex function
I am trying to integrate the real part of a specific entry in a Green function given by
G[E_] := Re[Inverse[E iF - H + I  L/2]][[13, 13]];

H and L are 16x16 matrices, iF is an identity matrix with the same dimensions. The same problem occurs also if I use some random matrices:
H = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {16, 16}];
L = RandomReal[{0, 14}, {16, 16}];
iF = IdentityMatrix[{16, 16}];

Plotting the real and imaginary part of G as a function of energy is not a problem, and the real part is approximately linear in the relevant energy range.
I need to integrate the real part of the function. When I try to do this, Mathematica runs for a few minutes and thereafter crashes (it quits the kernel). To integrate I use:
EH = -5.36;
NIntegrate[G[x], {x, EH - 0.01, EH + 0.01}]

I am using version 14.0.0.0 on Windows 64.

Please post the complete code you are using (including the definitions of iF, H, and L. Otherwise, we cannot test the code and provide any useful feedback.

It requires a very long and complicated simulation to get H and L, so it will be difficult to include it here. I would love to attach the matrices as a .dat file but this does not seem possible. iF = IdentityMatrix[{16, 16}]. I guess the problem will still be there if one uses a 16x16 matrix with random entries, but let me check

You don't need to include the code to generate H and L, just copy and paste their value.

Thanks for the very quick replies! The problem is also there if you just use:
H = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {16, 16}];
L = RandomReal[{0, 14}, {16, 16}];

I have updated the question with the necessary code to be able to test the problem.

I didn't wait long enough for the crash, but I think Mathematica gets stuck when NIntegrate tries to symbolically analyze your integrand. Therefore, you have to prevent this, either by doing Clear[G]; G[E_?NumericQ] := ..., or using NIntegrate[G[x], {x, EH - 0.01, EH + 0.01}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]. Either of these two methods work fine for me. Does it also work for you?

It works! Thank you so much @Domen!! (At least the first option you gave. My mathematica still crashes if I use the second option).

Ah, sorry, yeah, the second option doesn't actually work for me either. Anyhow, note that using _NumericQ is a commonly used trick in such cases :) Finally, perhaph someone else here has the time (and "authority") to determine whether the kernel crash in this case is actually some kind of a bug that shouldn't happen ...

That's really good to know!

I looks like a memory problem. It gobbles up all the memory and then crashes. Maybe a memory leak. I would report it to "support@wolfram.com".

Thanks, I will do that!
